# JMeter Groovy: print to log in class (static) (Apparent variable 'log' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local...)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, static-methods

I want to write to log inside static class in Groovy in JMeter. I can print to terminal inside and outside of class with `println` or `System.out.println`. How to do the trick with `log`? In code below all works except log.warn inside class, give error:

```
Script53.groovy: 13: Apparent variable 'log' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'log' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
```

Code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

class CalcMain {
static void main(def args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");

    println ("testing 1");
    System.out.println ("testing 2");
    log.warn("warn2");
  }
}
OUT.println("testing 4");
println("testing 5");
log.warn("warn 1");
CalcMain test1 = new CalcMain();
test1.main();
```

I tried web search but could not find an answer.

Comment: I'd say you have to define either a static `log` variable in your class or a local variable inside the method

Comment: @ injecteer, thank you, found the way which works as you advised.

Comment: What also should work is to use `@Log4j` groovy annotation

Comment: @ injecteer, doing `@Log4j log.warn("warn2");` with either space or new line gives `unexpected token: log @ line 20, column 5.` ... `unable to resolve class Log4j ,  unable to find class for annotation`

Comment: nonono, you have to annotate the class

Comment: @ injecteer, moved annotation to before class, now just: "unable to resolve class Log4j ,  unable to find class for annotation"

Comment: sigh... `import groovy.util.logging.Log4j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to send log as parameter to static method:

```
static void main(org.slf4j.Logger log) throws Exception {
```

Call method:

```
test1.main(log);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Groovy `@Log4j` annotation:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j

@Log4j
class CalcMain {
  static void main(def args) throws Exception {
    // some code
    log.info "hello there"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/ where it is advised to use `log` variable but also gives link to [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) class. I've tried to play with `Logger` class and it works:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class CalcMain {
    static void main(def args) throws Exception {
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("groovy");

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CalcMain.class);
    logger.warn("My warning");
    }
}
CalcMain test1 = new CalcMain();
test1.main();
```